# What is the meaning of Marge words?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

[Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116282/synopsis)

> She asks if he's done a lot count recently, and rather than answer

What is the meaning of the Marge words?

I specifically didn't understand "**lot count"** in the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Jerry Lundegaard is a car salesman. He works at a used car lot. "To do a lot count" means "to count all the cars in the used car lot". It's a similar expression to the more general "to do inventory".

I don't want to spoil the movie for you, in case you haven't seen it, but this is basically a major plot point that incriminates him.

Comment: spoil the movie how? I am just asking meaning of the sentence, so I can improve my vocabulary skills.